# Kubernetes service access internal service

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 services

- eclipse-mosquitto
- golang project consumer mqtt

I'm running in kubernetes
My mosquitto service

```
$ kubectl describe svc mosquitto -nproduction

Name:              mosquitto
Namespace:         production
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/instance=mosquitto
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=mosquitto
                   helm.sh/chart=mosquitto-2.4.1
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: mosquitto
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: production
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=mosquitto,app.kubernetes.io/name=mosquitto
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.98.173.157
IPs:               10.98.173.157
Port:              mqtt  1883/TCP
TargetPort:        mqtt/TCP
Endpoints:         10.44.0.1:1883
Port:              websocket  9090/TCP
TargetPort:        websocket/TCP
Endpoints:         10.44.0.1:9090
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

When I try acess with a golang sub

`network Error : dial tcp: lookup mosquitto on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.36.0.1:49071->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout`

Edit

I create a new VM and using docker-compose I run a mosquito, if I use external IP in my local machine it works, but if I use inside kubernetes mais golang project using a external IP don't works

Edit 2

I create demo chart using

`helm create demo`

After that I installed using

`helm upgrade -i demo demo --values demo/values.yaml`

My result

```
$ kubectl get pods

NAME                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
demo-fdf6f77b-fbb4c   1/1     Running   0          22s
```

So I tested

`helm test demo`

My result

```
NAME: demo
LAST DEPLOYED: Sat Jan 14 11:20:26 2023
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE:     demo-test-connection
Last Started:   Sat Jan 14 11:20:59 2023
Last Completed: Sat Jan 14 11:21:05 2023
Phase:          Failed
NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=demo,app.kubernetes.io/instance=demo" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  export CONTAINER_PORT=$(kubectl get pod --namespace default $POD_NAME -o jsonpath="{.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:$CONTAINER_PORT
Error: pod demo-test-connection failed
```

When I try see the logs

```
$ kubectl logs -f demo-test-connection
wget: bad address 'demo:80'
```

I don't where I need to search

This problem occurs when I try access external services

Comment: The error is for DNS lookup. Is your DNS operational?

Comment: try to use the fqdn once. Gos dns resolver is sometimes a bit funky.  See https://pkg.go.dev/net#hdr-Name_Resolution. The kind of dn you use relies on the search option in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: On that note, you can try to compile with netgo, perhaps that works better. netgo also doesnt understand mcast which may happen in kubernetes afaik.

Comment: In other Kubernetes clusters, I use just a "mosquito" and it works, I think this problem occurs because I use a oracle OCI always free